# I need help building an unproportional triangle in assembly and if/else statment also in assembly

Tags: assembly

So, i have this code for a triangle in assembly, the problem is that i'm only allowed to build proportional triangles like 75*75 and so on. I need to build a 135*40 and at some point I will to remove like 2 pixels at a time in a cicle can someone help me.

```
    mov cx, 176              ;coluna
    mov dx, 80             ;linha
    mov [cont], 75
     ciclo2:                   
     mov al,[cont]
     mov [cont2], al            ; cont2 will be initialized with 75, 74, ...
    ciclo1:                   
    ;ativa um pixel
    mov ah, 0Ch              
    mov al, 4                      
    mov bh, 0                
    int 10h
    dec cx
    dec byte [cont2]
    jnz ciclo1
mov cx, 176
dec dx
dec byte [cont]
jnz ciclo2
```

Comment: Is it a hollow triangle (just the border) or a filled triangle? Have you tried to draw it like a pyramid? You know, the top is just one pixel, the next line is 3 pixels, the next is 5, 7, 9, ... Get the idea?

Comment: the code i posted here does like 75 1st line 74 2nd line ... and it build a proportional triangle i didn't learned any other method of doing it. Also is easier to flip the triangle than the pyramid since i have to build some kind of flag

Comment: You are drawing the triangle from right to left. Are we allowed to draw it different? For example, from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in width between each line in a filled 135*40 pixel triangle won't be an integer. You could use floating-point arithmetic if you wanted to, but an easier approach would be to use fixed-point arithmetic. That is, scale the values by some number of bits (for example 8, which means multiplying by 256).
The bottom-most line will be 135 pixels wide, so start out with a value of 135 * 256 == 34560. The loop count for the inner loop will be the high byte of that word, which is 34560 >> 8 == 34560 / 256 == 135. Then we subtract (135 / 40) * 256 == 864 from this value after the inner loop, so that the next line will be slightly shorter:

```
; cont2_init is a word variable (2 bytes)
mov cx, 160               ;coluna
mov dx, 80               ;linha
mov [cont], 40
mov [cont2_init],34560  ; 34560 = 135 * 256
cicloc2:                   ;ciclo que repete a linha até fazer um quadrado
mov al,[cont2_init+1]        ; get the whole part of the fixed-point number
mov [cont2], al
        cicloc1:                    ;ciclo que cria a linha
        ;ativa um pixel
        mov ah, 0Ch               ;desenha nos pixeis do ecra
        mov al, 4                 ;determina a cor
        mov bh, 0                 ;numero de pagina grafica
        int 10h
        dec cx
        dec [cont2]
        jnz cicloc1
mov cx, 160
dec dx
sub [cont2_init],864  ; 864 = (135 / 40) * 256
dec [cont]
jnz cicloc2
```

Comment: compilation error on mov [cont2_init],34560 
i don't know if this works but i've never seen such thing. Isn't the number 34560 way too big for 32 bits assembly?

Comment: Problem #1 : what type is cont2_init so we can assign it 34560? If cont2_init is DD, how can we assign it to AL?

Comment: Well, you may have to adjust it for whatever assembler you're using. In NASM it would be `mov word [cont2_init],34560`

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: It's a word (mentioned in the answer). And I'm only moving one byte into `al` (the MSB of `cont2_init`).

Comment: I'm using FASM and i'm only on 1st year so i didn't learned a lot of theese things

Comment: It's probably `mov word [cont2_init],34560` in FASM syntax as well. And perhaps `sub word [cont2_init],864` for the subtraction. And remember that it needs be be declared with `rw` instead of `rb`.

Comment: Michael could you please try to explain to me what exactly mov al,[cont2_init+1] does since I have to explain this to my teacher as part of a project?

Comment: The 16-bit value in `cont2_init` is the width of the current line, multiplied by 256. Integer multiplication by 256 is the same as shifting 8 bits to the left. So in the 8 least significant bits we have the fractional part of the width, and in the 8 most significant bits we have the whole part of the width. When we initialize `cont2` we're only interested in the whole part, which is located 8 bits (1 byte) from the start of `cont2_init`, i.e. `[cont2_init+1]`.

Comment: I've understood this so far the only thing that is bugging my head in why [cont2_init +1] is it because of the 1 byte?

Comment: The `+1` simply means 1 byte ahead from the start of `cont2_int`.

Answer (score 0):

For a triangle 135 pixels wide, 40 pixels high, the width at row *r* is (135 * *r*) / 40. All integer math; no need for floating point or fixed point math. If you do the multiplication *before* dividing, then there is *no* loss of digits.

Just replace:

```
mov al,[cont]
mov [cont2], al
```

by:

```
mov al,[cont]   ; AL = row
mov bl,135
mul bl          ; AX = AL * BL = row * 135
mov bl,40
div bl          ; AL = AX / BL = (row * 135) / 40
mov [cont2], al
```

Notes:

- Careful with triangles with height > width; my calculation will reach zero before you reach the top row, and that will result in you drawing a row of 256 pixels. You have to test for zero before entering the loop to prevent that.
- For dimensions > 255, some more adjustments are necessary.
- `div` rounds 'down' (towards zero); if you prefer to round to the nearest integer, try ((135 * *r*) + (40 / 2)) / 40. Just `add ax,20` between `mul` and `div`.
- I didn't test it yet, sorry.